# Attempt to insert rows at specific section Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableview and after I get new data I want to update a specific section. So I update the corresponding models. My initial value of rows in that section was 3, now it suppose to be 5. I did following:

```
self?.addOperations(items, completion: {(pathes) in
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("output pathes - \(pathes)")
    for (index, item) in (self?.arrValues.enumerated())!{
      print("operations count - \(item.operations.count), section - \(index)")
    }
    self?.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self?.tableView.insertRows(at: pathes, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
    self?.tableView.endUpdates()
  }
})
```

Add operation is function that loads new data, adds it to arrValues (array that contain models of cell data), and then in completion block pass array of IndexPathObject.

That code crashes my app. In the log I can see:

> output pathes - [[1, 1]]
>   operations count - 7, section - 0
>   operations count - 5, section - 1

In my second section I have 5 values for now. And output IndexPath says that I have 2 rows in section (1). But the error says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

It all should work. Why doesn't it and how to fix it?

My delegate methods declared like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return arrValues.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return arrValues[section].operations.count
}
```

Comment: What about your table view data source methods? can you post them?

Comment: You are reading the error message wrong. Before the operation, you had 3 items in section 1. After the operation you have 5 items in section 1. However, there was only one item inserted using `insertRows`. The output for `pathes` says that you have inserted one indexpath (section 1, row 1).

Comment: @Sulthan how i can modify the code then?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban There is nothing wrong with this code. The problematic part will be the place where you are updating `arrValues`. It must be consistent with the `insertRows` calls. My bet is that `pathes` is not calculated correctly.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban or you can pass a paths array containing IndexPath with equal number of operations that you added to arrValues. Here you have added two operations then your paths array should contain two indexpath objects. How your passing paths to it? can you share that code?

Comment: Your issue is that you are adding two objects to your data model but your `pathes` variable only has one index path in it. If you add two rows, you need two index paths.